# Transparency in Gimp issue

Tags: gimp, transparency

So when I use Gimp, I do the same thing when I turn images transparent:

Select it by color, then hit clear.

But now instead of turning it transparent, it turns into my secondary color. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an alpha channel to your layer.

In the layers panel, right click the layer and choose "Add Alpha Channel".

Now when you delete/clear, it will delete to transparency.